# Flask-SQLAlchemy - retrieve Query.all() - All column in each row

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm running a Flask app with flask_SQLAlchemy and Postgres DB.

I want to print() all columns values for a row retrieved with query.all()

I've read over this document, but I was not able to retrieve what I'm looking for. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html 
I'm new to Alchemy though.

```
# the class model
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    reg_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False

# Query all users
users = Users.query.all()

# try to iterate
for row in users:
    print(row.all())
```

```
actual results:
before loop: 
    >>> <Users 1>, <Users 2>, <Users 3>, <Users 4>
after loop: 
    >>> error all() doesn't apply to row

expected result, not achieved:
    >>>
    {id="1", username="yyy", hash="xxx", reg_date"zzz", enabled"yyy"}   
    ....
    {id="n", username="ttt", hash="nnn", reg_date"jjjj", enabled"oooo"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`all` is used once in order to fetch all the records, then you should use the column names for display or anything else you'd like to do:

```py
users = Users.query.all()

for user in users:
    print(user.username)
    print(user.reg_date)
    print(f"<id={user.id}, username={user.username}>")
```

In order to achieve your desired result, which is to print the list of all users, you can print the `users` variable:

```py
print(users)
```

You should note that the `users` list contains `Users` objects, so printing the list will actually dump their representation - and if you want to control how these objects are displayed, you can use the `__repr__` method inside your `Users` model (object):

```py
def __repr__(self):
   return f"<id={self.id}, username={self.username}>"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've added the __repr__ function and it works for the sepecif configuration, allowing to see the keys and selected representation. However this requieres to edit the class structure. I'm looking for a  method (or other way) to access _ALL_ the contents of the `User`  object retrieved without pre-configuration. Possible?

Comment: Yes, you can loop through each object and print all of its properties, take a look at the loop section of the updated answer.

Comment: thanks, this achieves the results via explicit declarations of each key pair. I just would like to achieve the same result without explicit request for each column or key in each row; but have a print ALL results from each retrieved object.

Comment: Try `print(user.__dict__)` inside your `for` loop.

Comment: thanks, spot on! works great. Also I figured that: `user.username == (user.__dict__['username'])`.